# Can I give my Jade tree soda?

Tags: plant-care, jade

I have a Jade tree in my store and I just love her to bits. We try to give her water regularly, but sometimes at the end of the day some of the guys have leftover pop in the break room. Would it be safe to give this to her?

I've tried looking online but all references to pop end up meaning nothing and soda ends up meaning baking soda and I can't find anyone with experience.

Comment: Sugar is used in fertiliser spills. I would expect a reduction in other nutrients. But mostly more mould problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't have experience giving plants carbonated sugary beverages, the general opinion people I've encountered online have is that the sugar would be bad for the plants, might invite mold and other microbes, etc. I'm guessing the rest of the ingredients wouldn't be terribly toxic to plants, though.

Questions like this have been asked on gardening sites plenty of times, but usually they're wondering about the phosphoric acid in Coke (which doesn't exist in all soft drinks). Phosphoric acid can be good for plants, but you probably don't want all that sugar with it.

The sugar would probably be converted to alcohol and then to vinegar (acetic acid), eventually, is my guess. Acetate minerals can be good be good for plants, but concentrated vinegar when the plant is exposed to sun can kill plants.

According to [this site](https://abc11.com/abc11-science-club-basf-experiment-kids/3823534/), sugar can kill plants by causing reverse osmosis to occur. I don't know why reverse osmosis would kill plants, but I haven't studied it in that regard.

Comment: Wow, I was thinking specifically the sugars would be good for plants!! Okie dokie, we'll keep the pop far away from her. Or, ya know, the folks at the store can stop acting like teenagers and clean up their own pop from breaktime, I mean that's a thought!!